# Using django json fixture with model having Meta db_table set manually

Tags: python, django, orm

I have a django project with json fixtures generated with a model attribute like:

```
"model": "app_name.dog"
```

but I've set the model like this:

```
class Meta:
    managed = True
    db_table = 'dog'
```

and edited the json so that the model is like this:

```
"model": "dog"
```

and I get this when I try to loaddata:

```
django.core.serializers.base.DeserializationError: Problem installing fixture 'dog.json': not enough values to unpack (expected 2, got 1)
```

Since I removed the app name from the model to accomodate the db_table having no app_name prefix.

Is there a way to get django to ignore the need for an app name in the fixture?

Answer (score 1):

> Is there a way to get django to ignore the need for an app name in the fixture?

Nope, but I think you’re confusing the model name in the fixture with the db_table.  Even though you’ve changed your db_table to be `'dog'`, the django model name is still `'app_name.dog'` (ceteris paribus).  I am pretty sure if you change it back, it will still work just fine.